# Can i use external library in Samsung smart tv web app?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I am trying to develop HLS streaming web app using tizen studio. My question is can i use external library like https://www.mediaelementjs.com/ 
Please help i am new to tizen.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use external libraries in your web application. Just copy the libraries sources in your app and use it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfile.js"></script>
```

Later just refer to library in your JS code

https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/guide-import-external-library-web-application

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use external libs.

You just need to include the scripts in your HTML file as a regular web page.

I have worked before with [this](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) lib on Samsung TVs and overall has a good performance, however, if you want to have Samsung support for issues on streaming videos (m3u8/DRM) you need to use Samsung's player [here](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/multimedia/media-playback/using-avplay)

Example:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
<!-- notice: this will bring latest hls version always -->
```